# Ajax Form Submit

Tags: ajax, jquery, webforms

the form is submiting as normal request instead of Ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    StatusComments();

});


function StatusComments() {

    $('.comment').submit(function () {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
        return false;
    });

    var options = {
        beforeSubmit: showRequest,
        success: showResponse,
        resetForm: true
    };

    function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
        var textbox = $('#StatusMessageReplyMessage').val();
        alert(textbox);

    }

    function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {

    }

}
```

i have a similar one for Status update like this

```
function StatusUpdates() {
    $('#updateStatus').submit(function () {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
        return false; // prevent a new request
    });

    var options = {
        target: '.user-status',
        // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
        beforeSubmit: showRequest,
        // pre-submit callback 
        success: showResponse,
        // post-submit callback 
        // other available options: 
        //url:       url         // override for form's 'action' attribute 
        //type:      type        // 'get' or 'post', override for form's 'method' attribute 
        //dataType:  null        // 'xml', 'script', or 'json' (expected server response type) 
        //clearForm: true        // clear all form fields after successful submit 
        resetForm: true // reset the form after successful submit 
        // $.ajax options can be used here too, for example: 
        //timeout:   3000 
    };

    function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {

        var textbox = $('#StatusMessageMessage').val();
        if ((textbox == '') || (textbox == "What have you been eating ?")) {
            alert('Please Enter Something and click submit.');
            return false;
        } else {
            $('#StatusMessageMessage').attr('disabled', true);
        }

    }

    function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
        $('#StatusMessageMessage').attr('disabled', false);
        $('.share').slideUp("fast");
        $('#StatusMessageMessage').animate({
            "height": "18px"
        }, "fast");
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no JavaScript errors? Did you check your error console?

Comment: Does this occur in all browsers? It could be because there is an error in **any** of your javascripts that is causing the scripts to fail thus not sending AJAX.

Comment: nope i am not getting any error. the status message part which has similar code works. this is not :(

Comment: the full jQuery code http://pastebin.com/8Q4Rx8BH i have higlighted the function am trying to call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
 $('.comment').submit(function () {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
        return false;
    });
```

Try

```
 $('.comment').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: this makes an ajax call. but it goes to a different url than the form submit.

Comment: damn. i was tageting the click to the button instead of the form .so i wasnt working :(. thanks a lot